Document Footers Generated by WordprocessingDocument don't display the same on Word
I have been using the WordprocessingDocument to generate Word Document for a long time at this point and have not faced this issue till now. However, it is more prominent and gets worse when using this in conjecture with other libraries like aspose.
I created a Document who has 6 footers, depending on the section. It ideally goes like
Footer1 - Footer For Page 1 - Section 1 -> ""
Footer2 - Footer For OTher Pages - Section 1 -> "- PAGENUM -"
Footer3 - Footer For Section 2 -> ""
Footer4 - Footer For Section 3 -> "- APAGENUM -"
Footer5 - Footer For Section 4 -> ""
Footer6 - Footer For Section 5 -> "- BPAGENUM -"
The Document had proper references, and the proof for which are as follows:
Proof 1: When I look at the XML for the Docx (By changing the extension to zip). The XML from the zip file reflects that Yes, the footers are referenced correctly and are as expected.
Proof 2 for the same, I used the OpenXML Tool to read the Docx and I see the footers are referenced properly.
Now coming to the actual issue.

Given all the proof, when I open the document in Microsoft Word. MY Footers that were created are ignored completely, and only the Footer 1 and Footer 2 style is kept for All throughout the document regardless of what section we are on.
Even when the Latest Aspose is used to convert the WordProcessingDocument Memory Stream into Aspose, and then converting to Docx file yields to the same result. HOWEVER, aspose, gets rid of all the new footers, and keeps the same one shown in the word doc.

So I was looking for opinion as to what is the root cause of the problem? Is it an issue with my Footer Set-up for section? Is it a problem with Word? Is it a problem with Aspose?
PS: If someone could let me know if I am allowed to attach Docx/Zip files to the question I'd love to provide the 4 files, (Docx/Zip file of PreAspose and Docx/Zip file of PostAspose) I use the preAspose, and PostAspose as a reference to how the file converts.

Tried changing the footers, so it only has Text and no FieldCode like Pagenumber and all that, it still didn't reflect.
Tried Removing the Footer Section with no Text at all.
Tried Adding only 1 footer, works as expected.
Tried with Only 2 sections and 2 different types of footers no avail

Note: Initially the footer-refences when converting using Aspose were all over the place. While it worked as expected HOWEVER, the Footer refrences were mangled internally, so The footer for Section 2 reflected Footer of Section 4 and so on and so forth. When raised to Aspose, they fixed it. However, now it reflects what MS Word does.
PS: Remove if not valid Link to Expected Document Link to Actual Document

You may be able to include the flat OPC format (I.e. .xml) version of a small .docx as "plain text" at the end of your Question. But I don't know what the maximum question size is here. Otherwise, you have to put your .docx (and whatever) on a site that people here are willing to visit ,  and provide a link.

You can post the problem in Aspose.Words support forum and attach the problematic document there for testing: https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8

@jonsson I do not mind putting the file on a online platform and posting the link here, but wasn't sure if we are allowed to put a link with a doc file on Stack-Overflow.

@AlexeyNoskov There was a Similar Aspose issue posted, and IT technically works as expected. Since, Aspose at this point replicates what you would see on a MS Word program. It's just not as the XML is supposed to be if that makes sense. Which is why I made the post to be more of an OpenXML issue rather than Aspose.

re. "allowed links" I don't know either, but FWIW I have been able to download both the .docx files you posted. No time to look at them right now. Incidentally, the service you used told me the files would be deleted once downloaded, so if other people here say they can't see them, you may have to re-post them.
